# Execute system commands in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, unix

My requirement is to execute a system command like (ls) or C program when a trigger executes. Is there any way to create a trigger function to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use an untrusted language like PL/perl which would allow you to call operating system commands: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-trusted.html

Answer (score 20):

You can easily do what *@a_horse_with_no_name* suggests in his comment.  But there is also an interesting way to do it, using PL/pgSQL as the function language.

This uses a feature of the [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command, introduced in PostgreSQL 9.3.  It can now take a command as target/source, exactly where you'd use a filename or STDIN/STDOUT in normal cases:

> ```
> COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
>     FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
>     [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
> ```

Obviously, you need a table to put the output, but you can ignore it, if you want.

See a small example:

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_test (
    tt_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    command_output text
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_test_execute_command()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    COPY trigger_test (command_output) FROM PROGRAM 'echo 123';
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$;

CREATE TABLE trigger_test_source (
    s_id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TRIGGER tr_trigger_test_execute_command
    AFTER INSERT
    ON trigger_test_source
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_test_execute_command();

INSERT INTO trigger_test_source VALUES (2);

TABLE trigger_test;
 tt_id │ command_output 
───────┼────────────────
     1 │ 123
```

**Note:** the function needs to run with superuser rights - that is, either do the `INSERT` as a superuser, or define the function with `SECURITY DEFINER`.  In any other case, you'll get an error:

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from an external program
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

Comment: Note that the `TO PROGRAM` portion requires a string literal, so if you want a dynamic command you have to wrap the whole thing in `EXECUTE`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42626659/5419599.

Comment: Can you please help me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071706/running-system-command-in-plsql-and-use-return-value-in-insert

Answer (score 8):

If you just need to look at something relative to `$PGDATA` you can use [pg_ls_data](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE)

```
SELECT pg_ls_dir('pg_xlog');
```

Otherwise, a simple function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ls(location text) RETURNS text AS $BODY$
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    my $location = $_[0];
    my $output = `ls -l $location`;
    return($output);
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Will give you output like this:

```
user1@[local]:5432:user1:=# SELECT * FROM ls('/usr/local/pgsql/data');
                                       ls                                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 total 104                                                                              +
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql      4 Jan 14 14:33 PG_VERSION                              +
 drwx------  8 pgsql  pgsql      8 Jan 15 12:27 base                                    +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql     54 Feb  4 01:30 global                                  +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      4 Jan 15 12:57 pg_clog                                 +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_commit_ts                            +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_dynshmem                             +
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql   4458 Feb  4 01:29 pg_hba.conf                             +
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql   1725 Jan 20 15:29 pg_ident.conf                           +
 drwx------  4 pgsql  pgsql      5 Feb  4 02:14 pg_logical                              +
 drwx------  4 pgsql  pgsql      4 Jan 14 14:33 pg_multixact                            +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      3 Feb  4 01:29 pg_notify                               +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_replslot                             +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_serial                               +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_snapshots                            +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Feb  4 01:29 pg_stat                                 +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      8 Feb  4 02:17 pg_stat_tmp                             +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      3 Jan 15 13:08 pg_subtrans                             +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_tblspc                               +
 drwx------  2 pgsql  pgsql      2 Jan 14 14:33 pg_twophase                             +
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 pgsql  pgsql     29 Jan 14 14:34 pg_xlog -> /usr/local/pgsql/xlog/pg_xlog+
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql     88 Jan 14 14:33 postgresql.auto.conf                    +
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql  21821 Jan 20 15:27 postgresql.conf                         +
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql     53 Feb  4 01:29 postmaster.opts                         +
 -rw-------  1 pgsql  pgsql     79 Feb  4 01:29 postmaster.pid                          +

(1 row)

Time: 4.361 ms
user1@[local]:5432:user1:=#
```

Comment: Please note that this can also only be run with superuser rights (or using `SECURITY DEFINER`).

Comment: @dezso Quite right. Thank you for adding that point. =)

Answer (score 3):

Python-equivalent alternative to @Kassandry's Perl solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ls(location text) RETURNS text AS $BODY$
    global location
    import subprocess
    return subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", location])
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: FYI it's plpython3u in python3 (sudo apt install postgresql-plpython3-12 in Ubuntu 18 and then create extension plpython3u in psql to install the language into postgres)